# The coarse moduli schemes of the "Shimura stacks" are the canonical models of the corresponding Shimura varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, shimura-varieties

Let $F$ be a number field, $B$ a central simple algebra over $F$, $*$ a positive involution on $B$ which fixes $F$, and
$O_B$ a maximal $O_F$-order of $B$ which is stable under $*$.
Assume that $(B, *)$ is type C, i.e., for every embedding $F \to \mathbb{C}$, the pair $(B \otimes_F \mathbb{C}, *)$ satisfies (C) of Prop 8.3 of [1].
Let $L$ be a left $O_B$-module which is finitely generated and free over $O_F$,
$\varphi$ a nondegenerate alternating $\mathbb{Z}$-biliner form $L \times L \to \mathbb{Z}$ satisfying $\varphi(bx, y) = \varphi(x, b^*y)$.
Let $(G,X)$ be the Shimura datum associated with $(B,*,L \otimes \mathbb{Q}, \varphi)$, and
$E$ the reflex field of it.
Let $K$ be an compact open normal subgroup of $G(\hat{\mathbb{Z}})$.

Then we can define the Shimura variety $\operatorname{Sh}_K$ as a normal algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and the smooth algebraic stack $\mathscr{X}_K$ over $E$ whose objects are abelian schemes with the level structures associated with $(B, *, L \otimes \mathbb{Q}, \varphi)$ satisfying the Kottwitz' determinantal condition, and the morphisms of this stack are the isoorphisms between them.
Let $X_K$ be its coarse moduli space.
It is a scheme by [2, 7.2.3.10].

As a complex manifold $\operatorname{Sh}_K(\mathbb{C})$ is a well-behaved double coset, and it is canonically bijective to the set of isomorphism classes of $\mathscr{X}_K (\mathbb{C})$.
We identify them.

The following statements seem to be well-known and fundamental, however, I could not find any reference.

> (1) There exists a canonical map $(\mathscr{X}_K)_{\mathbb{C}} \to (\operatorname{Sh}_K)_{\mathbb{C}}$ which is the coarse moduli.
> (Here "canonical" means that this map sends abelian varieties (with level structures) $A \in \mathscr{X}_K(\mathbb{C})$ to the same abelian varieties (with level structures) $A \in \operatorname{Sh}_K(\mathbb{C})$.)
>
> (2) $X_K$ is the canonical model of $\operatorname{Sh}_K$.

Could you please provide me with references of these highlighted statements?
(Especially I want (2). It seems not to be so difficult to show (1).)

Here's what I have tried:

I think that (1) is proven as follows:
First assume $K$ is neat. Then $\mathscr{X}_K = X_K$.
Let $A$ be the universal object over $X_K$.
We can consider $A$ as the holomorphic family of abelian varieties with level structures over the complex manifold $X_K(\mathbb{C})$.
Hence it induces the holomorphic morphism $X_K(\mathbb{C}) \to \operatorname{Sh}_K(\mathbb{C})$.
By Borel's theorem it is the algebraic map $(X_K)_{\mathbb{C}} \to (\operatorname{Sh}_K)_{\mathbb{C}}$.
This is isomorphic, and is the desired map.
In general case, divide this map by the level group, we obtain the desired map $(\mathscr{X}_K)_{\mathbb{C}} \to (\operatorname{Sh}_K)_{\mathbb{C}}$.

And (2) seems to be proven breifly in [1, section 14, p126, subsection "Simple PEL Shimura varieties of type A or C"] without reference nor details.
(The case of Sigel moduli varieties is [1, prop 14.12], whose original is probably [3, theorem 4.21].)

[7, theorem 11.18] is similar to (1) of the highlighted statements, however, whose definition of $\mathcal{F}_K$ is slightly different from our $\mathscr{X}_K$.

In the last paragraph of section 8 of [4], the author said that (2) holds if the level group $K$ is contained in $G(\mathbb{A}^p)$, where $\mathbb{A}^p$ is the ring of finite adeles with trivial $p$-adic components.
How about the case $K \subseteq G(\hat{\mathbb{Z}})$?

I've seen some papers which states these highlighted statements for various $G$, for example [5, prop 4.3] and [6, prop 3.7] state them for unitary groups.
However, their proofs are like "It can be proven similarly to [4] or [3]", and contain no details.

reference:

[1] Milne, Introduction to Shimura varieties.

[2] Lan, Arithmetic compactifications of PEL-type Shimura varieties.

[3] Deligne, Travaux de Shimura.

[4] Kottwitz, Points on some Shimura Varieties over Finite Fields.

[5] Stephen Kudla, Michael Rapoport, Special cycles on unitary Shimura varieties II: global theory.

[6] Michael Rapoport, Brian Smithling, Wei Zhang, Arithmetic diagonal cycles on unitary Shimura varieties.

[7] Milne, Shimura varieties and moduli.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by satisfying (C) of 8.4 in [1]? That in some extension of $F$, $B$ becomes a matrix algebra with $*$ the matrix transposition?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks for your comment. Yes it is. I editted it.

Comment: Re section 8 of [4]: the condition on level groups contained in $G(\mathbb{A}_f^{(p)})$ is about integral models over the localisation $O_{E, p}$, which is a very different (and much harder) question than canonical models over $E$. What Kottwitz is doing is: given a level $K^p$ away from $p$, he looks for $O_{E, p}$-schemes whose base extension to $E$ is the Shimura variety of level $K := K^p \cdot G(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

Comment: You can certainly take $K^p$ to be contained in $G(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^{(p)})$, so that $K^p G(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is contained in $G(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})$ (but you don't have to).

Comment: Have a look at: Deligne, Pierre,
Variétés de Shimura: interprétation modulaire, et techniques de construction de modèles canoniques.  Automorphic forms, representations and L-functions (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Oregon State Univ., Corvallis, Ore., 1977), Part 2, pp. 247–289,
Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., XXXIII, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I., 1979.

Comment: I found that theorem 3.31 of Milne's "Shimura Varieties and Motives" probably is an answer of (2) of the highlighted statement.